# Installing Node.js and Updating Python

Tags: python, node.js, centos

So I am trying to install node.js on my server. I have managed to wget and extract the .tar file into a folder, then cd'd into it and used the './configure' command. I get this error message:

```
[~/node-v0.8.8]# ./configure  File "./configure", line 325
    o['default_configuration'] = 'Debug' if options.debug else 'Release'
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

After rigorous googling, I have found out that this is caused by Python and is because of my Python version (which is 2.4).

Now I am trying to update Python, and the installation is working fine, but I'm thinking it's not installing where it needs to? Because after install, I type python -V and it still says it's on 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've `make install`d a newer version of Python and it's not reporting the newer version in `python -V`, then most likely your installation did not go to a place located in your `$PATH` env var.

I'd suggest reviewing the output of `make install` to see where it was actually installing the files to, and updating your `$PATH` to use this new location.

Answer (score 0):

If your old (and Python 2.4 is elderly in computing terms) Python was installed via an OS package, it's probably in /usr/bin, /usr/lib, etc. If you installed the new one via configure/make/make install, it probably went into /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, etc. and your path search, shared-library search, etc. are probably missing it because they can still find the old one.

If you can, use your package manager to update your Python version. If not, redo the installation with the appropriate `--prefix=...` option to configure (it might take some poking around to figure out what that options should be).

Answer (score 0):

Note that another solution to this issue (unable to compile node.js) is to use the binary distributions for Linux which have been [published since 0.8.6](http://blog.nodejs.org/2012/08/07/node-v0-8-6-stable/)

Here's the script I used:

```bsh
# get the latest stable binary 
# (modify version number based on what you find in that folder)
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.8.20-linux-x64.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/
sudo tar xzvf ~/node-v0.8.20-linux-x64.tar.gz --strip=1
```